# When data is required to be submitted, is it before publishing the paper or after paper is published?

Tags: phd, engineering, intellectual-property

Shall I submit all my data and models to my supervisor before publishing the paper or after the paper is published? I want to submit my data and models after paper has been published, atleast abstract has been sent to a conference and accepted. Because I am afraid that my data and models may be used to publish paper in other students name. What is the general norm that is foolwed in these scenario? What should I tell to my supervisor?

Answer (score 1):

**Discuss the impending publication with your supervisor before submitting it for publication**. A few reasons for this:

- If your supervisor's name is going to be on the publication, you should absolutely talk to him/her about it, because publications should never be submitted unless they are approved by all authors.
- If your supervisor cares about you, then he/she will want to know how you are progressing. Having a paper ready for publication is a notable milestone, so it is something to update your supervisor about.

If your data and models end up being used by other students, all the better for you, since it means they consider your work important enough to work on. They're not going to be able to publish before you since presumably your data and models are complicated enough that they won't be able to complete the work before your paper gets accepted, i.e. you have precedence.

The only scenario in which this could be a problem is if your supervisor is unethical enough to steal your results, give them to another student, and get them published in the new student's name ... but in that case, why is he/she still your supervisor? It would indicate it's well past time to change supervisors.